# JetBrains Rider EAP RC - nuget.org feed is missing

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, jetbrains-ide, rider

I started using Rider but I can't browse packages because there is no feed as you can see in the picture.

[image: No feed]

Any idea?

Comment: First of all check a 'Sources' tab

Comment: There were no sources. NuGet.Config couldn't be loaded. It was a permissions issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a permissions issue. Don't know why, but it seems that the first time I run Rider with root, so NuGet.Config needed root privileges.

Solved it deleting NuGet.Config and creating project again (needed).